# Passing multiple values to SUMIFS function in Excel

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have Twocolumns A, B ..I am trying to get the sum of A like below.

```
=SUMIFS(
       sheet1!$A:$A, 
       sheet1!$B:$B, ("AB", "BC", "CD")
       )
```

But this formula is not working.
Please suggest me.

Comment: What are you trying to do? To sum values in `$A:$A` in rows where values `$B:$B` are equal to one of these three values?

Comment: Yes  Taosique.  Its not one of those values but can match with one or more of those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((sheet1!$B:$B={"AB","BC","CD"})*(sheet1!$A:$A))
```

or alternatively you can use an **array** formula:

```
=SUM(IF(sheet1!$B:$B={"AB","BC","CD"},sheet1!$A:$A,0))
```

enter formula in the formula bar and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it......

Comment: Is there any forumula where we don't need to repeat the same formula.

Comment: I will try the second formula.Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer with new formula (look at the first formula)

Comment: Hi  The formula is working only thing we need to do is we need to replace ; with , :)

Comment: )) it depends on local settings) first formula (in my updated answer) is more attractive for me)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing your intention right, you should have:

```
=SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$B:$B,"AB")+SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$B:$B,"BC")+SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$B:$B,"CD")
```

Comment: yes @Taosique , if we add forumals seprately my formula becomes very big and will be confusing as I have 20 more lines in the formula. I am looking if there is any alternative.

Comment: Yes, there is. But it requres you to add two helper columns. Interested?

Answer (score 0):

Add two helper columns: in `D:D` you have the list of valid values. In `C:C` you have a formula like this (change `;` to `,`). In `F1` you have your sum like this:

```
=SUMIFS($A:$A,$C:$C,FALSE)
```

[image]

Now you can add any number of valid criteria in column `D:D`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS` to return an array (one for each criterion) and then `SUM` to sum those, i.e.

`=SUM(SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,sheet1!$B:$B,{"AB","BC","CD"}))`

This way retains the speed and efficiency of SUMIFS without needing repetition

If you have your criteria values in a range of cells you can simply reference the range, but use `SUMPRODUCT` to avoid "array entry"

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,sheet1!$B:$B,Z2:Z4))`

where Z2:Z4 contains the criteria

Note: in both of these `SUMIFS` does all the "heavy lifting" - `SUM/SUMPRODUCT` is used simply to sum the resulting array